# Editing access database in multiuser mode. File lock situation

Tags: ms-access, file-sharing, multi-user

I have this application that uses an MS Access DB file( .mdb ) and I want to use this application with multi-user environment.( or more than one user should be able to edit the database simultaneously ).

I have this application on a shared folder on Windows Server 2012 R2, and all the users using the application have all the permissions of the folder in which the .mdb file is and all the permissions of **.mdb** file itself now the situation is as following

When the user1 opens the application and saves an entry in the database it works all fine on the other hand if after this user2 tries to save an entry in the database he get's this error

> The Microsoft access database engine cannot open or write to the file
>   It is already opened exclusively by another user or you need
>   permission to view or write it's data**

Now after searching for this, I got a few answers that says that the **user1** who opened this file previously doesn't have all the permissions so MS Access DB Engine opened it in exclusive mode and created a lock for the other users preventing them from editing the same file, but all the users have full access so this is not possible.

While if either of users Restart the application they are able to edit the database preventing others to do the same.

I think that restarting the application loads a fresh edited version of the db file allowing users to edit it while in doing so changing the instance of the file used by other users.
Please guide me
Thanks already.

Comment: are there any temporary tables or objects during the save process?  common practice is to split the database, and allow each user to have their own front-end copy of the .mdb. This usually resolves a couple issue, Including situations similar to what you describe. One of the major major advantages is, if corruption occurs only one person is affected, no everyone (unless a back-end table is corrupted of course).

Comment: I have this .mdb file I can't even open it forget about splitting it

Comment: who developed the file?  there should be an .accdb file somewhere? How do you make changes or update the file if necessary?  If you're just working off of a single .mdb with no way to work on it and no way to properly split it and share it, it's not a good situation. Keep frequent backups.. you're going to need them.

Comment: it's a clients file it's a data entry software actually and using this program we enter data in that table, after some digging I tried opening file in the **Libre Office Calc** and it's opening but **Libre Calc** is making a copy of it naming it an unassigned file, if there is some method where some users enter some data and after that I could just merge all that data in a single file that would be great but I can't alter of edit the .mdb file itself, and that's for putting your time to help you've been a great help.